# What is the preferred way to check if an optional has a value without using it?

Tags: coding-standards, swift-language

Which of these is the ideal way to check if a value exists without caring exactly what its value is?

```swift
if let _ = flags[.showField] { showField() }

if flags[.showField] != nil { showField() }
```

In the first case, it seems more Swift-y to use `if let _ =` and futureproofs it (I can imagine a future where Apple says you must ask the optional if it has a value instead of comparing to `nil`). Additionally, if you come back to modify the code and find you need the value, you can just replace the `_` with a name.

In the second case, it reads more naturally and is reflexive with `if x == nil` in a way that `if let _ =` is not.

**Is one of these preferred over the other? If so, which and why?**

Comment: Use your first example if you need more Swift-y, future-proofing and the name placeholder.  Use your second example if reading more naturally and reflexivity is more important to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything particularly Swifty about the first method.

I would go with the second approach.

1. I think the second one is more understandable, especially for new language learners, for whom the `if let` syntax is foreign.
2. The second approach can be negated. `if x != nil` can become `if x == nil` with a single character change, but there's nothing similar in the `if let _ = x` case.

Comment: Those are both great points!